# New to Ansible - adding users to servers depending on type

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm relatively new to ansible, and am trying to write a playbook which adds users to a group of servers depending on the user_type (which i'm trying to define)...

So... my playbook looks a little something like this....

```
- name: add user  
      user:  
        name={{ item }}  
        state=present  
        shell=/bin/bash  
      with_items: "{{ userlist }}"  
      tags: add_new_user  
      become: true
```

`userlist` is defined in a seperate yml file:

```
---
userlist:
user1
user2
user3
```

Defined in my hosts file, I have 3 groups:

```
[grp1]
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1

[grp2]
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.3

[grp3] 
192.168.0.4
```

What i'm thinking of doing is adding these grp types to my userlist, so it'd look a little something like this:

```
---
userlist:
user1  grp1
user2  grp2
user3  grp3
```

I'm trying to work out how on earth my playbook is going to work out which users get added to which servers - I know i'll need to declare another variable so my playbook know that user1 is getting added to servers in grp1, but I can't work out how?

Comment: Use the [formatting tools](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) to make your posts readable.

Comment: please consider marking something as an answer when you are happy.

Comment: 2 days and no reply :-(

Comment: Why do we even bother...

Answer (score 0):

One simple method: Use [group vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#group-variables):

If you have only one user per server, you can define them in the inventory (you need to adapt your play to not loop and use `newuser` as var instead):

```
[grp1:vars]
newuser=user1
```

If there are more users, you need either a YAML inventory (instead of ini) or use a group var file: Create a subdir called `group_vars` below the dir containing the inventory file with one file per group, e.g.

```
$ cat grp1

userlist: 
   - user1
   - user2
```

and then `userlist` would be defined separately for every group.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is via host variables or hostgroup variables. You can read up how to do that here in [the ansible manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/vars/host_group_vars.html?highlight=host_var). Another more advanced option is via custom facts or scripts. U need to read up about variable ordering to avoid unexpected behaviour.

also I would like to point some small syntax errors. U can't start a declaration with an accolade({). And use colons when putting a single declaration per line. Like so:

invetory_file:

```
[grp1]
host1
host2
host3

[grp2]
host4
host5
host6

[grp3]
host1
host4
```

playbook.yml:

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: adding users to x
      user:  
        name: "{{ item }}  "
        state: present  
        shell: /bin/bash  
      with_items: "{{ userlist }}"  
      tags: add_new_user
```

group_vars/grp1.yml:

```
---
userlist:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
```

host_vars/host5.yml

```
---
userlist:
  - user1
  - user4
  - user10
```